# R purrr::partial -- how does it handle partialized arguments?

Tags: r, purrr, partial

I have been an enthusiastic user of R's `purrr` package for quite a while and recently ran into a question regarding `purrr::partial`.  Suppose I define a two-argument function

```
f <- function(x, y) x + y
```

and partialize it by setting the `y` argument to some global variable's value:

```
yy <- 1
fp <- partial(f, y = !!yy)
fp(3)                       # 3 + 1 = 4
```

Unquoting `yy` (that is, using `y = !!yy` as opposed to `y = yy`) causes `yy` to be evaluated only once when `fp` is created; in particular, modifying `yy` after this step does not alter `fp`:

```
yy <- 2
fp(3)                       # still: 3 + 1 = 4
```

Here is my question: What exactly does `partial` do after evaluating `yy`? -- I see two possibilities:

1. The value of `yy` is "hard-wired" into the body of `fp`, meaning that it is not passed as an argument when `fp` is called.
2. The value of `yy` is more or less treated as if it was the `y` argument's default value (without the option of overriding the default), meaning that `fp` internally calls `f` (or a copy of it) to which the value of `yy` is silently passed as an argument matched with `y`.  In this case `fp` is no more than a syntactic wrapper around `f`.

Trying to explore the second possibility I modfied the definition of `f` after defining `fp`.  This does not alter `fp`, meaning that `fp` does not contain any outside reference to `f`; however, this does not rule out the (theoretical) possibility of `fp` containing a copy of the old version of `f`.  (Conclusion: This approach does not help.)

Some practical background to motivate my question:  In my current project I have defined lots of functions that use (a) arguments varying from call to call, (b) arguments representing "configuration data" or "domain knowledge".  The data matched with the (b) arguments (which may be considerable amounts of data) do not change from call to call, but may change when I commit an update; in any case I believe this data should not be hard-coded in my functions.  My strategy is to read the configuration data from some files at start-up time and integrate it into my functions by partializing the arguments in (b).  Applying the partialized functions via `purrr::pmap` to some tibbles turned out to be kind of slow, which made me suspect that the configuration data may still be passed when the function is called -- hence my question.  (If anyone has some thoughts on the "partialization strategy" briefly described above, I will be keenly interested in these, too.)

Comment: Regarding your "partialization strategy" it would be great if you could (1) show a simple example (2) explain where your problem is and (3) what you tried to do (if I understand you tried to modify `f`, but to what end?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is option 2. Try:

```
f <- function(x, y) x + y
yy <- 5
fp1 <- partial(f, y = !! yy)
debugonce(f)
fp1(3)
```

Here you can see that, if in RStudio, the debugger will open the original function `f` to which the arguments `x = 3` and `y = 5` are passed. However, the partialized function is not calling the real function `f` but a quoted copy of it. If you change `f` after it has been partialzed, the debugger won't find it anymore.

```
f <- function(x, y) x + y
yy <- 5
fp1 <- partial(f, y = !! yy)
f <- function(x, y) x + 2 * y
debugonce(f)
fp1(3) # debugger will not open
```

---

It is possible to mimic the behavior of `partial` by constructing the function to partialize yourself. However, in this case neither `f` nor `yy` are captured so changing them will effect the output of your partialized function:

```r
f <- function(x, y) x + y
yy <- 5

# similar to `partial` but captures neither `f` nor `yy`
fp2 <- function(x) f(x, yy) 
fp2(3)
#> [1] 8
# so if yy changes, so will the output of fp2
yy <- 10
fp2(3)
#> [1] 13
# and if f changes, so will the output of fp2
f <- function(x, y) x + 2 * y
fp2(3)
#> [1] 23
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

To better understand how `partial` is working we can construct a `simple_partial` function the following way:

```r
library(rlang)

f <- function(x, y) x + y
yy <- 5

simple_partial <- function(.f, ...) {
  
  # capture arguments
  args <- enquos(...)
  # capture function
  fn_expr <- enexpr(.f)
  # construct call with function and supplied arguments 
  # in the ... go all arguments which will be supplied later
  call <- call_modify(call2(.f), !!! args, ... = )
  # turn call into a quosure (= expr and environment where it should be evaluated)
  call <- new_quosure(call, caller_env())
  # create child environment of current environment and turn it into a data mask
  mask <- new_data_mask(env())
  # return this function
  function(...) {
    # bind the ... from current environment to the data mask
    env_bind(mask, ... = env_get(current_env(), "..."))
    # evaluate the quoted call in the data mask where all additional values can be found
    eval_tidy(call, mask)
  }

}

fp3 <- simple_partial(f, y = !! yy)
fp3(1)
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimTeaFan for your very detailed and enlightening answer.  I will have to spend a little more time to look into your definition of `simple_partial` though.  Very helpful and much appreciated!

Comment: @Ed7 Thanks! `simple_partial` basically contains the core functionality of the original `partial`, but all `if` statements which handle special cases are stripped.